# Backup and Restore - can't restore

Tags: backup

I'm confused when it comes to restoring backups. Installed Magento 2.4.2-p1, set periodical backups in webgui which can't be restored using webgui - after clicking "Rollback" nothing happens (tried in 2 different browsers and in incognito mode as well).
Update:
Each "Rollback" action button creates in console following errors:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'

and when followed would lead to JS script:

```
return backup.rollback(&#039;media&#039;, &#039;1630195203&#039;);
```

What suppose to look more like(?):
return backup.rollback('media', '1630195203');

So, I did try in cli:

> bin/magento setup:rollback -m 1621213202_media.tgz

and it gave me following

> The rollback file is invalid. Verify the file and try again.

Which means that gui and cli backups are not compatible?
Next I created backups in cli:

> bin/magento setup:backup --code --db --media

So far, so good but not for a long, when I was trying to restore them:

> bin/magento setup:rollback -c 1621428237_filesystem_code.tgz -d
> 1621428237_db.sql -m 1621428237_filesystem_media.tgz

I received another error:

> The rollback can't be executed because not all files are writable.

Files ownership is set as:

> 'Magento user':'web server group'

and permissions

> find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec
> chmod g+w {} + find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc
> -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +

What am I missing?

Comment: Updated my test instance to 2.4.3 and still is the same. Do I need to run commands as root?